# Opinions on Server Side vs Client Side Web Framework

Tags: architecture, frameworks, client

I'm very curious about the community's opinions on server side frameworks (like Django and RoR) versus client side frameworks (like SproutCore and ExtJS).

I know its a a bit of a false dichotomy since there is no reason why one cannot use both server and client side framework.  However in practical terms this can be a huge headache.

Just for example: cultivating an expertise in 2 different languages, 2 different APIs, and 2 different framework syntaxes just to achieve a single goal is terribly inefficient.

The strategy that feels right to me is to pick one client OR server side framework as the primary, and then supplement where necessary with something very lightweight on the other side.  For example, use RoR on the server as the primary supplemented on the client by jQuery.  Or use ExtJS on the client as the primary supplemented by PHP on the server.

Right now I'm not sure which side of the fence to fall on and am interested in the community's opinions and experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Its completely a false dichotomy. They solve different subproblems of a goal. Apparently though, Microsoft ASP.NET stuff is pretty good at integrating Client-side with Server side (I have never used it myself however, so please correct me if I'm wrong).

Client-side libraries are focused on presenting the data to the user.

Server-side libraries need to be focused on CRUD functionality (Create, Read, Update, Delete), and authentication the user. When data needs to be centralized, it needs to be dealt with on the server.

No server-side library will ever have drag-or-drop or accessibility features. No client-side library will ever have MySQL and Access Control List implementations.

Comment: That is not entirely the case.  Theoretically, if my application simply integrates various cloud-based data services, I could do everything client-side in ExtJS RESTfully passing JSON around -- no need for any server-side dev.  On the other hand I could do everything in RoR, letting Rails deal with writing the client side framework scripts -- no need to directly touch JavaScript or a JavaScript framework.  So, as we move past monolithic software the overlap between client and server frameworks increases and the question of client vs. server side framework become a very reasonable one.

Comment: @niblettes: in theory, yes, your first case is true. Of course, you could use any Client Framework (C++ / QT, Java, .NET/C#, GTK+). While it would be a "web program", it doesn't centralize any of the data onto a single server, you probably wouldn't have users / authentication, etc. etc. or anything that makes it feel webby. The second case (RoR creating client side scripts) is more likely, but you always can create a richer experience for the user if you touch the Javascript yourself.

Comment: In the end, a pure client program is always possible. (after all, computer programs and applications existed before the Web and RESTful calls). A pure server program is also possible (web applications existed before Javascript and JS Frameworks). But again, you aren't going to get a centralized hub of data unless you build the server yourself, and you'll never get "Rich User Experience" without building the client yourself. (ie: drag and drop, gestures, etc. etc.)

Comment: So then to revisit the question, I wasn't asking about pure client vs pure server side.  But rather I was wondering about people's opinions on server-side primary (ie, RoR) with a light client-side secondary framework (ie jquery), VS client-side primary (ie, ExtJS) with a light server-side secondary framework (ie, php).  The idea being to focus effort on one primary technology/language, and only using as much technology as necessary and no more.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Dragontamer.  Server side frameworks and client side frameworks solve different problems.

Yes, you can access the server with a client side framework like jQuery or EXT, but you still need to communicate with an application server on the server.

Application server (ASP, PHP, ColdFusion, etc) would be the M and the C in an MVC app, and serve up the "V".  The client side framework would make the V pretty and add client side functionality (e.g. manipulating the data provided by the application server, such as sorting table data without refreshing the page).

Two completely different animals that serve two completely different purposes.

Comment: Sure the app would need to communicate with services on the server side, but if I'm accessing cloud-based data services with published APIs that accept and respond with valid JSON, then these service are blackboxes to me (and I to them) and theoretically I can communicate with them equally through client or server side frameworks -- hence the question.

Also, if you use a client side framework like SproutCore the "V" in your example above itself has an MVC.  I've never nested MVCs, but I suspect its something I wouldn't want to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

That IMHO is more than a question, it is a problem. Either way, you will end up rewriting code from one side to the other because you suddenly will realize that to add something to that functionality in the server, you need something from the client and vice versa, after some changes you will realize that your functionality in the client would run better in the server or the other way around, so you will rewrite code back and forth from the server to the client and viceversa.

The underlying problem is the lack of a  high level language both for the Web and the cloud, that can run in the server and in the browser, so that no code rewrite is necessary for communication locally or remotely, so each piece of functionality can be migrated at installation time depending on the capabilities of each node or better, at runtime, depending on capabilities and load conditions, from one location to another.

It can be done.